# Is there a curve that supports both pairing checks and Montgomery ladders?

Tags: pairings, isogeny

Is there a curve that supports both?
Or are there two curves that can be mapped between using a 2-isogeny that support pairing checks on one and Montgomery ladders on the other?

Is there a paper on it?